# Magento 2 - The words "admin" and "index" appear twice in the admin URL

Tags: admin, url, base-url

I have Magento 2.1.9 installed. After a futile attempt to change the admin URL, it resulted to me not gaining access to the admin panel. After resolving that issue, the admin URL displays like this: `http://www.example.com.ng/admin/admin/index/index/key/fd90f73bc589242812ccb991b515dc5672066759dd7e43fb7354a11cc6d38744/`

The following is what I have it the `app/etc/env.php` file:

```
return array (

  'backend' => 

  array (

    'frontName' => 'admin',

  ),
```

It would be great, if I can have this URL: `http://www.exaple.com/admin/`. But if not, I would simply opt to revert back to Magento 2 default setting. How to I achieve this?

Any insight would be much appreciated. And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**http://www.example.com.ng/admin/admin/index/index**

is the  default setting.Don't worry about this.

If you hit http://www.example.com.ng/admin your magento admin url

it will automatically 302 redirect to `{base_url}/{admin_frontendName}/admin/index/index/key/{key}/`

Comment: Much appreciated